# Trying to create scrolling horizontal thumbnail navigation that hides on left side when not in use

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll, gallery, thumbnails

I am trying recreate the following type of scrolling thumbnail navigation as described in the following tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/10/scrollable-thumbs-menu/

I require my thumbs to slide out horizontally from the left. I have amended the code to the best of my abilities, but I can't get it to work. (Think the problem is in the top third of the jquery).

Here is what I have to date:

HTML

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="sc_menu_wrapper">
            <div class="sc_menu">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/4.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/5.jpg" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
/* Navigation Style */
ul.menu{
position: fixed;
top: 0px; 
left:0px;
width: 100%;
}

ul.menu li{
position:relative;
width: 100% 
}

ul.menu li > a{
position:absolute;
top:300px;
left:0px;
width:40px;
height:200px;
background-color:#e7e7e8;
}

/* Thumb Scrolling Style */

div.sc_menu_wrapper {
position: absolute;
right: 0px; 
height: 220px;
overflow: hidden;
top: 300px; 
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

div.sc_menu {
height: 200px; 
visibility:hidden;
}

.sc_menu a {
display: block;
background-color:#e7e7e8;
}
.sc_menu img {
display: block;
border: none;
opacity:0.3;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

JQUERY

```
  $(function(){

      // function to make the thumbs menu scrollable 
            function buildThumbs($elem){
                var $wrapper        = $elem.next();
                var $menu       = $wrapper.find('.sc_menu');
                var inactiveMargin  = 220;

                // move the scroll down to the beggining (move as much as the height of the menu)

                $wrapper.scrollRight($menu.outerHeight());

               //when moving the mouse up or down, the wrapper moves (scrolls) up or down 

                $wrapper.bind('mousemove',function(e){

                    var wrapperWidth    = $wrapper.width();
                    var menuWidth   = $menu.outerWidth() + 2 * inactiveMargin;
                    var top     = (e.pageX - $wrapper.offset().right) * (menuWidth - wrapperWidth) / wrapperWidth - inactiveMargin;

                   $wrapper.scrollRight(right+10);
                });
            }

      var stacktime;

      $('#menu li > a').bind('mouseover',function () {
          var $this = $(this);

          buildThumbs($this);

          var pos   =   $this.next().find('a').size();
          var f =   function(){
              if(pos==0) clearTimeout(stacktime);
              $this.next().find('a:nth-child('+pos+')').css('visibility','visible');
              --pos;
          };

          // each thumb will appear with a delay 
          stacktime = setInterval(f , 50);
      });


      /// on mouseleave of the whole <li> the scrollable area is hidden 
      $('#menu li').bind('mouseleave',function () {
          var $this = $(this);
          clearTimeout(stacktime);
          $this.find('.sc_menu').css('visibility','hidden').find('a').css('visibility','hidden');
          $this.find('.sc_menu_wrapper').css('visibility','hidden');
      });

      // when hovering a thumb, change its opacity 
      $('.sc_menu a').hover(
      function () {
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.find('img')
          .stop()
          .animate({'opacity':'1.0'},400);
      },
      function () {
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.find('img')
          .stop()
          .animate({'opacity':'0.3'},400);
      }
  );
  });
```

Wondering if some eagle eye might be able to point out where I am going wrong. As my knowledge of JQuery is limited, I'm guessing it is in there.

I really appreciate anyone taking the time to look this over.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6eTHr/) for you :)

<del>I couldn't get your code to work with the demo</del>, but the first thing that needs changing is all the rights to left. There is no such thing as `scrollRight`. Here is just the first function in the code with those problems fixed.

```
  // function to make the thumbs menu scrollable 
        function buildThumbs($elem){
            var $wrapper       = $elem.next();
            var $menu          = $wrapper.find('.sc_menu');
            var inactiveMargin = 220;

            // move the scroll down to the beggining (move as much as the height of the menu)

            $wrapper.scrollLeft($menu.outerHeight());

           //when moving the mouse up or down, the wrapper moves (scrolls) up or down 

            $wrapper.bind('mousemove',function(e){

                var wrapperWidth = $wrapper.width();
                var menuWidth    = $menu.outerWidth() + 2 * inactiveMargin;
                var left         = (e.pageX - $wrapper.offset().left) * (menuWidth - wrapperWidth) / wrapperWidth - inactiveMargin;

               $wrapper.scrollLeft(left+10);
            });
        }
```

Oh and add a `float:left` in this bit of CSS:

```
.sc_menu img {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 float: left;
 opacity:0.3;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

---

Updated to make the scrolling and highlight work properly - it may not be the most efficient method of doing this, but I didn't change the code that much from the original. [Updated demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6eTHr/1/).

CSS

```
/* Navigation Style */
ul.menu{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left:0px;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.menu li{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%
}

ul.menu li > a {
 display: block;
 position:absolute;
 top:300px;
 left:0px;
 width:40px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:#e7e7e8;
}

/* Thumb Scrolling Style */

div.sc_menu_wrapper {
 position: relative;
 height: 220px;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 300px;
 left: 0px;
 visibility:hidden;
}

div.sc_menu {
 height: 195px;
 visibility:hidden;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.sc_menu a {
 background-color:#e7e7e8;
}
.sc_menu img {
 height: 195px;
 width: 130px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 border: none;
 opacity:0.3;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

Script

```
$(function(){
 // function to make the thumbs menu scrollable
 function buildThumbs($elem) {
  var $wrapper = $elem.next();
  var $menu = $wrapper.find('.sc_menu');
  var leftOffset = $wrapper.offset().left;

  // move the scroll left to the beggining
  $wrapper.scrollLeft(0);
  // make menuWidth (width of all images side by side) include the offset
  var menuWidth = leftOffset;
  // calculate the width of the menu by adding each image width (includes any padding, border & margin)
  $menu.find('img').each(function(){
   $(this).css('left', menuWidth );
   menuWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  // set calculated menu width - if not done, the images will wrap to the next line
  $menu.width(menuWidth);

  //when moving the mouse left or right, the wrapper moves (scrolls) left or right
  $wrapper.bind('mousemove', function(e){
   var wrapperWidth = $wrapper.outerWidth(true);
   var left = ( e.pageX - leftOffset ) * (menuWidth - wrapperWidth) / wrapperWidth;
   $wrapper.scrollLeft(left);
  });
 }

 var stacktime;
 $('#menu li > a').bind('mouseover', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  // set up thumbnail scrolling
  buildThumbs($this);
  var pos = 0,
      len = $this.next().find('a').length;
  var f = function () {
   if (pos > len) { clearTimeout(stacktime); }
   $this.next().find('a:nth-child(' + pos + ')').css('visibility', 'visible');
   pos++;
  };
  // each thumb will appear with a delay
  stacktime = setInterval(f, 50);
 });

 // on mouseleave, the whole the scrollable area is hidden
 $('#menu li').bind('mouseleave', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  clearTimeout(stacktime);
  $this.find('.sc_menu').css('visibility', 'hidden').find('a').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $this.find('.sc_menu_wrapper').css('visibility', 'hidden');
 });

 // when hovering a thumb, change its opacity
 $('.sc_menu a').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('img').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1.0' }, 400);
 }, function () {
  $(this).find('img').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0.3' }, 400);
 });
});
```

Comment: Oh my goodness  thank you so very, very much for taking the time to help me sort this out. (I cannot believe the generosity of people in this community).  I will be working on my site this evening and will be back to give you due kudos (check mark and arrow up) if/when I get it running. 

And that jsfiddle site looks amazing. Thank you very much for sharing the link. I obviously have to look into this resource.

I could kiss your wet little nose, Fudgey :) Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Fudgey,

I tried it and it works perfectly... coming out from the right, opening towards the left. I know you have already done of ton of work on this - if you could just offer some advice on which JQuery CSS positioning selector I should use in order to get it opening out from the lefthand side, heading towards the right (hope this makes sense?)- which is what is required for this project. Is it $(selector).offset()? I've never used these selectors before. I'll keep plugging away here, regardless, and post my results if I succeed.

Comment: Hiya, I got the images to pop out from the left, but then I realized it doesn't scroll left & right like the tutorial scrolled up and down... give me a little more time to work on it and I'll update the post above :)

Comment: Ok I've updated the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/6eTHr/1/), I hope that is what you wanted! :)

Comment: You did it! I can't believe it! I was working on it until the wee hours and couldn't figure it out. (Before that, I had struggled with it for almost a week). But it seems you were working on it for hours, too (but with results!).

How can I ever thank you enough? I will be dissecting your code to figure out how you made it work. This has already taught me so much.

I am just so incredibly grateful and humbled for the effort and work you put into finding this solution for me. You have made my day! My month!

I sincerely thank you again, Fudgey. In time I hope to be able to pay it forward.

Comment: *bow with flurry of hand gestures*... hehe, I hope I commented it enough to help you dissect it :P

Comment: hah hah - You're way too adorable for words. And smart as a whip! Yes - I can see what you did through your helpful comments. I don't think I'd have figured it out on my own, though. You truly saved my life... Fudgey, you're the best! :)